# How color the background of website two different colors?

Tags: html, css, padding, background-color

**This is a really hard question to formulate**, so I've included a screenshot of a website design that I made in Pages (Mac) - I did so by using different colored blocks and stacking them on top of one another to create the desired effect that can be seen in the first screenshot.

My question is: **How do I emulate** this, **different colored backgrounds in HTML?**

I've tried coloring my padding differently with an HTML tag in CSS ( HTML

```
{ padding: 10%; background-color: #ebecef; }
```

) but I failed to fully encapsulate my dream. I've attempted to make divs (since they're 'block tags') and color them differently, but it didn't work.

[Pages Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KQRg.png)

[High Contrast Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbyFW.png)

High Contrast Page Description: Blue would be the base background color, Orange would be the inset/overlay, and pink would be the div navbar but its painted the same color as the inset/overlay as seen in the first picture.

To try and clarify: **How would one either, go about creating blocks of a different color and transforming them into a certain position, or, creating a sort of two-tone effect for the background color that's 'inseted' into itself or overlayed** (whichever's easiest or works) **like seen in the picture** (The grey being the base color and the white-ish color being the additional color that's been inseted/overlayed.)**?**

I really hope I explained that well enough, if you could help it would be greatly appreciated,

*DeSept*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially with a responive design in mind, I would do it with a grid. You just need 3 boxes and can get the title to collide with an offset or correct the padding. Just make sure to set the z-index to push it on front.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 40% auto 30px;
  grid-template-rows: 48px auto;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#title {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 38px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menu {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

#content {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: -1;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="title">Title</div>
  <div id="menu">Menu Link</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Random text content...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a new thing for me the use of grid on css. Thanks, now I have a nice studying weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the linear-gradient syntax if you want the two colors to blend mor depending on if you want a hard or soft line between colors. Find out more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

example syntax below:

`#grad { background-color: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow); }`

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic level you can achieve this using nested divs, setting the width and height in combination with the css `position` property and `top`, `left` css properties. Like below:

```
    <div style="width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background-color: blue;position: relative;">
      <div style="height: inherit; width: inherit;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 80px;margin-right: 20%">
          <div style="width: 340px; height: 80px; background-color: green; float: right;margin-right: 10%">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 80%;height: 80%;background-color: yellow;margin: auto auto;">
        <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 40px;left:120px">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-voice-zgt9k?file=/index.html:0-830

However, this solution is not responsive and is very basic; as an alternative you could look at either CSS Grid or Flexbox to achieve the layout you are looking for in the attached images.

CSS Flexbox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

CSS Grid:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: hard to follow that logic -> gives a lot of headache to temper with. Also this will create bad habits and editing the style is way harder then necessary later on. Definetly agree on the Grid or Flexbox solution.

Comment: Agreed, the above is for indication on how to achieve what's being asked; I've not provided a copy and paste solution for the purpose of allowing some thought to be applied to question. Grid or Flexbox will provide a comprehensive solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redraw your picture. That's not the same but you can use my styles for your goal. I used Nav as a `div`, but there are a lot of better Nav examples on internet like [Bootstrap NAV](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). This is not responsive, then you have to add `@media` css there, and maybe use collapse navbar.

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
.Center80{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80vw;
}
.Menu{
  height: 20px;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #a119aa;
}
.SecondColor{
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.SecondColor h1 {
  transform: translate(0px,-13px);
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="Center80 Nav" align="right">
    <div class="Menu">
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="SecondColor Center80">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: despite the fact that it is still miles away from the wanted outcome. It also will bring him on the wrong track by learnign wrong methods. I just want to mention div.FirstColor which is a useless Box. It would be easier and way more effective to simply define the body { background: blue; }. aswell as VW is used here in an ineffective way. Way easier to simply set a body padding and then use 100% width for all parent divs and auto width for child divs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, yes, FirstColor was a useless Box, I changed my answer and use a body bg-color instead. But I think padding on body is not a better solution, mmm maybe it's because vw require to declare it in any container? because if it's a class it's not the scenario, we can reuse that class for all the container that needs that width. and maybe using another width in anothe page of the system, if we declare on body, we have to override it if we need more or less space.

Comment: the thing with a body-padding is, that it works globally for everything. If you want to overwrite the padding you just need to use margin with a negative value.Really not a big efford and easier to handle. if he wants to adjust the left and right padding/margin he only need to do this with the body-padding instead of editing the margin of every child element. You also have to think, that some goign to edit the style later on and if you dont do it the right way, you have a mess then.

Comment: Mmm yes, I supposed that it's for globally things, I prefer to use class for it, I really prefer not using margin-left negative if I can use container classes for it, the thing with me is that I don't like to use css on elements directly, because later we have to override it for new requires.... we will continue fighting for our own practices,  if you noticed haha